Celery task chain should execute it once per API request
Lets say we have a python web app using fastapi and celery (5.4). After the user request comes I want to execute celery task in this order
a_si = get_dataA.si(.....)
b_si = get_dataB.si(.....)
c_si = get_dataC.si(.....)

b_r_si = build_relationship_B.si(...)
c_r_si = build_relationship_C.si(...)

chain_1 = chain(group(a_si, b_si), b_r_si)  # if a_si, b_si already ran use the result otherwise execute it
chain_2 = chain(group(a_si, b_si, c_si), c_r_si) # if a_si, b_si already ran use the result     otherwise execute it

group(chain_1, chain_2).apply_async()

Here issue is a_si and b_si are getting called multiple time per API request. how can I make it run only once then use its result in chains.
During debugging I came to know that its running multiple times, how to make it run once?
